# Manipulate HTML5 dialog in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to create a simple configuration dialog with close icon on top-right, but can't think of how to handle this in React. In other frameworks, I can simply use selector, and then use .showModal()/close() to open/close a dialog. However, I think we're not allowed, or not recommended to directly manipulate DOM in React, so I wonder what's the proper way in this case.

My project outline

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  ...
  ...
  return(
    <div>
      <ConfigPage />
      <ConfigButton />
      <MainContents />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want to open a dialog, which is `<ConfigPage />`, by pressing the `<ConfigButton />` I set, and close it by pressing the icon on the dialog.

**config-page.js**

```
class ConfigPage extends Component {
  ...
  ...
  return(
    <dialog>
      <header>
        <div>
          <i onClick={someCallback}></i>               
        </div>
      </header>
      <section></section>
    </dialog>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the HTML5 dialog also has an `open` attribute, correct? Instead of calling show/hide you could manipulate this attribute -

```js
class ConfigPage extends Component {
  ...
  ...
  return(
    <dialog open={this.state.showDialog ? 'open' : false}>
      <header>
        <div>
          <i onClick={someCallback}></i>               
        </div>
      </header>
      <section></section>
    </dialog>
  )
}
```

And when you want to show/hide call `this.setState({showDialog: true})` (or false)

Here's a js fiddle with a proof-of-concept: https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/193969/

Comment: Hello, is there anything might cause `open` attribute can't be removed properly? I added a state showDialog, and did `() => {this.setState({showDialog: false})}` inside the <i 
onClick={...here...}>, but it didn't remove the open attribute.
p.s. I opened the dialog by doing show call in console.

Comment: Can you post your render method?

Comment: If you're showing/hiding the dialog from the console as well it will throw off the react component because the state will no longer match the dialog's state.

Comment: Oops...I got it. I haven't noticed I had messed up the state from the console. Thanks!

Comment: open attribute won't trap focus, you shall use `showModal`

Comment: According to [html spec documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#attr-dialog-open) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog#simple_example): "Opening dialogs via HTMLDialogElement.show() is preferred over the toggling of the boolean open attribute."

Comment: And what if I close with ESC? Wouldn't it break the React state?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. You can hide a react component by return null from the `render` function. You can define a flag in the `state` that determines weather or not your component is visible. Here is a simple example.

```
class Modal extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: true;
    };
    this.onCloseClick = this.onCloseClick.bind(this);
  }


  onCloseClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      isOpen: false,
    });
  }


  render(){
    if (!this.state.isOpen) return null;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onCloseClick}>
          Close
        </button>
        <h1>What up, this a modal</h1>
      <div>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach! It works fine, but the other answer is closer to my idea.